# Conditional Probability and KL Divergence

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning

Let $\mathbb{P}_A$ denote the distribution conditioned on $A$ such that for any measurable set $C$, we have $\mathbb{P}_A(C)=\mathbb{P}(A\cap C)/\mathbb{P}(A)$. On page 80 of the citation, author claimed that the KL divergence $D(\mathbb{P}_A||\mathbb{P})=\log\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$. I don'k know how to derive such an equality and I found there exists a term with respect to $\mathbb{P}(C)$ and $\mathbb{P}(C\cap A)$ that cannot be canceled out.

*Wainwright, Martin J.*, High-dimensional statistics. A non-asymptotic viewpoint,  [ZBL07021501](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:07021501).

Comment: How are $C$-dependent terms showing up in the KL divergence computation? KL is an integral of a function of the R-N detivative, so there should be nothing set-valued in the argument. Concretely, it is trivial that $P_A \ll P$. Assuming $P(A) > 0,$ show that $\frac{\mathrm{d}P_A}{\mathrm{d}P}(x) = \frac{\mathbf{1}_A(x)}{P(A)} =:\varphi(x). $ Then $D(P_A\|P) = \mathbb{E}_{X \sim P}[ \varphi(X) \log\varphi(X)]$ is easily seen to equal $\log(1/P(A))$.

Comment: BTW - this is very straightforward in a discrete setting, and you should work that out first. I gave the above because you used the term measurable above, so I'm guessing that you're working in a generic probability space, in which case the R-N derivative route is the cleanest way to do things.